# How to prevent child managed object context from stalling an app?

Tags: swift, core-data

I'd like to use a childContext (NSManagedObjectContext) for a detail view where the user can edit parameters of a model. The idea is that unless the user saves the detail view I can simply scrap any changes. If they do save their changes I can propagate the changes to the parentContext.

What's happening is that 100% of the CPU is being consumed when I execute the code that makes a childContext and a copy of the NSManagedObject using the following code.

The app works fine without the childContext approach but I also want to observe changes to the childContext to keep the detail view UI up to date. So I need a childContext, plus this supposed to work so I must be missing something.

Can anyone advise on why this is happening and what to do about it?

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        childContext.parent = childContext
        let childEntry = childContext.object(with: foodEntry.objectID) as? FoodEntry
        addFoodVC.foodEntry = childEntry
        addFoodVC.context = childContext
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addFoodVC, animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this line `childContext.parent = childContext` is causing an infinite recursion loop when you try to fetch the object.

Try setting the parent with the app's main context instead of the child context itself.

Comment: Wow. I goofed big time on that one. Thanks for the save.